# React.js - calling REST APIs inside GraphQL queries

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql

I'm working on React.js, GraphQL, and REST API.
My query returns only 10 results but there are 60 overall.
I think this has something to do with pagination but I'm not sure how to get all 60 results.
Here's my code

index.js

```
const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: "https://swapi.dev/api/",
  credentials: "same-origin",
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: restLink,
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

MovieTable.js

```
const MovieTable = (props) => {
  const GET_PLANETS = gql`
    query GetPlanets {
      planets @rest(type: "Planet", path: "planets") {
        results
      }
    }
  `;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PLANETS);

  console.log(data);

  if (loading) {
    // to do:
  }

  if (error) {
    // to do:
  }

  return (<div>...</div>);
};

export default MovieTable;
```

https://swapi.dev/api/planets - URL in the browser displays 60 planets and I don't understand why my results are limited to 10 and I'm not sure how to get all of them.

Can anybody help, please?